# Redirect links to app store go to mobile safari browser first

Tags: ios, mobile, safari, app-store

Is there a way to not have this happen? I don't want to take my users to the safari browser before getting redirected to the App Store.

Right now if I send out an email link, it hits my server (for click tracking purposes), and then our server will redirect the to the app store. The problem is that this methodology will cause safari to pop open momentarily.

Is there a way to design it such that the user will not have safari opened and we can still track the click?

Comment: request to your server to get redirect URL first and open this URL

Comment: That will open safari first though. I want to know if there's a way to avoid opening safari at all.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do it in two different steps. First send a NSURLRequest to your server using NSURLConnection and separately open the AppStore URL.

Alternatively or in addition use the iTunes Referral Program for tracking.